# How do i get my truncate function to not give error

Tags: reactjs

//This is the function

`function truncate(str, n) { return str?.length > n ? str.substr(0, n - 1) + "..." : str; };`

i have tried to remove the ? from str?.length, but it only gives more errors and i keep getting "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Comment: The error doesn't seem to point to the truncate function at all. The function in itself doesn't throw errors.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related to react, should have javascript tag instead

Comment: This  seems like a webpack problem